# Как правильно типизировать свойства объекта ts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, типы

Я создал компонент **Icon**, в пропсы которого приходит ключ объекта, далее по этому ключу я достаю SVG из объекта. Как мне правильно типизировать этот объект, чтобы в ручную не описывать каждое свойство?

**Icon.ts**

```
import { FC } from "react";
import icons from "assets/icons/icons";

interface Props {
  name: string;
  size: string;
}

export const Icon: FC<Props> = ({ name, size }) => {

  const icon = icons[name]; // name: any

  return <div className={styles.icon} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={icon}></div>;
};
```

**icons.ts**

```
export default {
  heartSVG: `<svg></svg>`,
};
```

Comment: @EzioMercer, это то же самое

Comment: `name: keyof typeof icons;`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, это сработало! Я пытался сделать почти также, но не указал keyof, поэтому не получилось. Если добавишь это как ответ, я укажу что он верный)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) позволяет получить тип переменной.
[`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#handbook-content) позволяет получить типы ключей у переданного типа.

В итоге получится следующее

```
name: keyof typeof icons;
```